# Fastest way of testing for a NULL field (null detection)

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I use two different ways of checking whether a database field `column_b` is not `NULL`. Which is faster and why?

First query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE column_b IS NOT NULL;
```

Second query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE column_b = column_b;
```

There is no index on `column_b`.

Comment: What are the explain plans?

Comment: The naive answer is (1) is faster. But SQL optimisers are extremely clever. And it would depend on any indexes you'd set up.

Comment: Should we assume columb has an index or no index?

Comment: first statement use 2 op and second is use one ?

Comment: I do not know the null values are most or not. Because the table is transactional. so I cant predict the  vaules content

Comment: What size of table are we talking about? what is the distribution of values in columnb? are most null? not null? is each record more or less unique? or is there lots of repetition in a defined set? Too many unknowns which imo makes it a tough question to answer.  Also what version of oracle?  If we're going to be evaluating the Cost bast Optimizer (CBO), we need to know which version.

Comment: @xQbert: This optimisation doesn't involve the CBO, just like [join elimination](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/01/join-elimination-an-essential-optimiser-feature-for-advanced-sql-usage/) it does not depend on any cost model at all.

Comment: Apparently I have a flawed understanding.  i'll do some more reading!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For standard, scalar data types, they're both the same on Oracle (I tried 12c and 11g), as you get two times the same execution plan. ([see MT0's answer for an edge case when this isn't true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46367529/521799))

Proof:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (columnb NUMBER);

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE columnb IS NOT NULL;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE (dbms_xplan.display);

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE columnb = columnb;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE (dbms_xplan.display);
```

In both cases, I'm getting:

```
Plan hash value: 3804444429

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |          |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLUMNB" IS NOT NULL)
```

#### Now, even if you did add an index....

```sql
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (columnb);
```

... you'd still get the same plan for both queries:

```
Plan hash value: 887433238

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |          |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | MY_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLUMNB" IS NOT NULL)
```

#### What if the column was `NOT NULL`?

Let's try this:

```sql
DROP INDEX my_index; -- Get back to the initial situation
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY columnb NUMBER NOT NULL;
```

The plans I'm getting now are these, with the entire predicate having been eliminated, in both cases:

```
Plan hash value: 3804444429

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |          |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Conclusion

Since you don't get any advantage from the "clever" approach, simply don't do it and write the `IS NOT NULL` predicate to be more clear.

By the way, this is such an interesting question and optimisation type, [I've blogged about it and about similar optimisations more in depth here](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/).

Comment: Could this vary by version?  Data volume/distribution etc?  I think (I'll have to work on proving in downtime) depending on statistics on large or uneven data sets with varying null's it could.

Comment: @xQbert: I'm pretty sure it doesn't. The optimisation of transforming the `X = X` predicate into a `NOT NULL` predicate seems so trivial that I'm taking bets even Oracle 7 could have done it.

Comment: @xQbert: Besides, I don't see how the costs / statistics could affect this decision.

Comment: @LukasEder thanks for answer, so before oracle 7 , **b=b** used instead of **not null** ? in any condition you say they are same?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar: That Oracle 7 thing was just a wild guess. I don't know when this optimisation was introduced, but it appears so basic that I wouldn't be surprised if it was there from the beginning. But no, I'm not saying people used `b = b` instead of `b IS NOT NULL`. No one sane does / did something as "clever" as that :) And yes, they are the same, logically, but one is more readable than the other.

Comment: @LukasEder - They are not always the same if the column contains an `OBJECT` type.

Comment: @MT0: Yes, already updated my answer with a link to yours. Cool, I didn't know you could implement `MATCH` on `OBJECT` types this way.

Comment: You can name the function anything (`MATCH` is just the name I used) but you need to declare it as either a [`MAP MEMBER FUNCTION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10799/adobjbas.htm#sthref144) or an [`ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10799/adobjbas.htm#sthref149) for it to be used to compare objects.

Answer (score 2):

They are not always the same if you are using Objects:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb1c7/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE coord AS OBJECT (
  x NUMBER,
  y NUMBER,
  ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION match (l coord) RETURN INTEGER
);
/
CREATE TYPE BODY coord AS 
  ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION match (l coord) RETURN INTEGER IS 
  BEGIN 
    RETURN ( x   * 100 + y )
         - ( l.x * 100 + l.y);
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1, col2 ) AS
  SELECT 1, coord( 2, 3 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, coord( 0, 2 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, coord( NULL, 2 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, NULL FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  col2 IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb1c7/1/0)**:

```
| COL1 |                       COL2 |
|------|----------------------------|
|    1 | oracle.sql.STRUCT@10394576 |
|    2 | oracle.sql.STRUCT@11ddf9d5 |
|    3 | oracle.sql.STRUCT@595e9c7d |
```

**Explain Plan**:

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 3383972830 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |            |    3 |   123 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | TABLE_NAME |    3 |   123 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter(SYS_OP_NOEXPAND("COL2") IS NOT NULL)
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  col2 = col2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb1c7/1/1)**:

```
| COL1 |                       COL2 |
|------|----------------------------|
|    1 | oracle.sql.STRUCT@35c56f09 |
|    2 | oracle.sql.STRUCT@1f0e893f |
```

**Explain Plan**:

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 3383972830 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |            |    1 |    41 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | TABLE_NAME |    1 |    41 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter("COORD"."MATCH"("COL2","COL2")=0)
```